# Shared Library Linker Path Search algorithm in HP-UX

Tags: hp-ux, unsatisfiedlinkerror

What is the shared library linking path search algorithm for HP-UX (IPF-64Bit ) used while compiling with aCC ?

I am trying to build a project but it looks like SHLIB_PATH environment variable is never used for library searching. I've to explicitly specify the library locations using -L option while building.

Comment: What is your HP-UX version and architecture?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no `SHLIB_PATH` on IA64 but on PA-RISC. You should use standard `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Works for me quite well on 11.23 and 11.31.

Comment: I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to locations of libs also, still not working.

Comment: Can you find the shared lib manually? More overy, why don't you recompile it with IA64N?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot link a PA-RISC lib to a IA64 binary. You can only run PA-RISC binaries on IA64.

Comment: The file has been created in correctly. `sl` has been used for PA-RISC files. `so` is the new standard. Did you read the manpages of `aCC` how it searches for libs? Where is the lib located exactly?

Comment: Lib is in a user created directory having full permission. I looked into man page of `ld` instead of `aCC` and it seems like setting `LPATH` is working. Though still i can't find the default library search path.

Comment: I found some more info here http://www.filibeto.org/unix/hp-ux/lib/dev-tools/linker-lib-ug/linkerdifferencesiapa.htm#linktimedifferences
Acc. to it `.sl` is supported for compatibility in IA64.